# Hasse Symbol for ramified primes

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, ramification

My Reference is [https://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/249BW09Page/handouts/cfthistory.pdf](https://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/249BW09Page/handouts/cfthistory.pdf)
In chapter 7, page 17, Keith says

> For example, $(\alpha, L/K)_v$ lies in the common decomposition group
> $D(w|v)$ for all places $w|v$ on $L$

for unramified places $v$ it follows from definition, but it feels that for ramified primes there is something non-trivial to say, or at least I don't see why it is obvious.

Can someone point me in a direction for showing that?